# How do I validate DTO in spring RequestHandlerInterceptor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've a RequestHandlerInterceptor. I want to do some pre-processing in preHandle() method. The pre-processing has to be done only when the DTO is correct ( e.g., when the input json matches the schema defined in Java Object. )

How do I validate if the DTO matches the schema ?

Constraints:

1. My interceptor is in a separate Java project. I can't have other projects dependent on the project where interceptor is.
2. The input json is deserialized using a custom deserializer class (this deserializer is registered with my Web app, I don't know how at the moment ), hence I cannot simple use ObjectMapper and see if the fields match.

I've tried this DataBinder way:

preHandle():

```
    ServletRequestDataBinder binder = new ServletRequestDataBinder(((HandlerMethod) handler).getBean());
    binder.bind(request);
    LOGGER.log("Binding result has errors: " + binder.getBindingResult().hasErrors());
```

But hasErrors always returns false.

To put it in other words, I need to do whatever magic the @RequestBody annotation does to validate and map the input json to Java Object in my interceptor.

Comment: I think you have a design problem here, DTO validation is done by spring boot after preHandle of the interceptor. and even of you do the validation twice, it is bad practive  as it intruduce consistency problem.